# What's a minimal buildout.cfg file for a Python package?

Tags: python, virtualenv, buildout

I'm developing a small Python package - a bunch of `*.py` files. It has some dependencies, and I'd like to use virtualenv and buildout to create its own, separated environment for development and I'd like to package it as an Python egg.

What recipe should I use?

Should I put my project into `eggs`, `develop`, or `parts` variable?

Should I keep my code in `src`, `parts` or in `develop-eggs` folder?

And where do I add dependencies then?

I read some tutorials, but they look way too complicated for me - all I need is just a simple example with an explanation.

Comment: Do you *need* a buildout? For my really simple python packages I don't create one; I just use `setup.py test` to run my tests and that is it. See [this simple package](https://github.com/mjpieters/setuptools_subversion/) for example.

Comment: The answer below by @Skirmantas is correct. A `setup.py` to make your code available as a package. A `develop = .` in `buildout.cfg` to tell buildout to effectively do `python setup.py develop` on your local package. `parts=` is only to tell buildout which sections in its config file to execute. `eggs=` in the `[scripts]` section/part is how you configure which eggs/packages you want included in the path of the `bin/*` scripts buildout generates there.

Answer (score 3):

There might be other ways. This is how I like to structure my packages:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py

setup.py

    from setuptools import setup

    setup(...
          packages=['mypackage'],
          package_dir={'mypackage': 'mypackage'})

          entry_points="""
              [console_scripts]
              mypackage-script = mypackage.script:main
          """,
  )


buildout.cfg

    [buildout]
    parts =
        scripts
    eggs =
        mypackage
        django
        lxml
        ...

    develop = .

    [scripts]
    recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
    eggs =
        ${buildout:eggs}
    scripts =
        mypackage-script

    interpreter = python
```